# Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of print statement" expected) in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I am new in symfony, trying to study the conditional statement. Having difficulty in adding the sum of all in my for loop.

Question: How can I fix the error "Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of print statement" expected) and may I know what is the cause of having this error?(for future reference)

**My twig file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }} </title>
</head>
<body>
    {% set number1 = 2 %}
    {% set number2 = 1 %}
    {% set total = 0 %}

    {# If-else condition#}

    <!-- {% if number1 > number2 %}
        {{ "Number 1 is greater than to number 2"}}

    {% else %}

        {{ "Number 2 is greater than to number 1"}}
    {% endif %} -->

    {# If-elseif-else condition #}
<!-- 
    {% if number1 == number2 %}
        {{ "Number 1 number 2 is equal"}}

    {% elseif number1 > number2 %}
        {{ "Number 1 is greater than to number 2"}}

    {% else %}

        {{ "Number 2 is greater than to number 1"}}
    {% endif %} -->

    {# For loop #}
<!-- 
    {% for i in 1..10 %}
        {{ i }}
    {% endfor %} -->

    {# For loop getting the sum #}

    {% for i in 1..10 %}
        {{ total = total + i }}
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

`+=` is not a valid twig operator. This is what is causing the error. If you need to increment the variable you will need to do it in a separate statement.

`{{ total += i }}` should be `{% set total = total + i %} {{ total }}`

Comment: I updated my post. Im getting confused, so you used set total.so every time it change it will be updated? Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: `+=` is the increment assignment operator. The way your code was written it would update the variable in each loop. But that is the wrong syntax. Your updated question is also incorrect. `{{ }}` is used to print something.

Comment: {{ }} is for displaying the result and if you want to display sentences/word right? {%%} is for the logic(like for loop,if-else condition) but i didnt expect you have to declare it as set again.